# Looking for the best Array method to compare objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

Sample array

```js
var myItems = [{height:500, width:400},{height:500, width:800},{height:500, width:700}]
```

Instead of doing

```js
if(myItems[0].height !== myItems[1].height && myItems[0].height !== myItems[2].height && myItems[1].height !== myItems[2].height){
 // do smth about it
}
```

with larger arrays this code gonna get ridiculous, so I played with this

```js
if (myItems.reduce((x,y)=>x.height!==y.height)){
 // do the same thing
}
```

The problem is, this always returns `true` even if the above values are in place, all items have same `height` value.

Comment: what is the result of all?

Comment: This is not how `reduce` works. The first argument in the function is an _aggregator_, the second argument is the next item. The initial value of the aggregator is taken from the second argument passed to `reduce`, or the first item in the array; you might want to start with a boolean value instead of an object. It looks like you’re asking for an n² comparison (every object with every object) rather than a sequential one, so this won’t work with a single `reduce`.

Comment: Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62461165/13638059) it might help you

Comment: @user4642212 I'm open to any suggestion on how that might look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting this to a set for height and then compare the lengths for your array and the heightSet.

```js
var myItems = [{height:500, width:400},{height:500, width:800},{height:500, width:700}];

var heightSet = [...new Set(myItems.map(x => x.height))];

console.log(myItems.length === heightSet.length);
```

Comment: I cannot use the `[...arr]` spread operator with buble.

Comment: Use `[...something]` is equivalent to `Array.from(something)` @thednp

Comment: This works fine, however I need something to work with IE10+, any other ideas?